# Explain how scaling of the inverse square law breaks down at a stars surface

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, thermal-radiation, laws-of-physics, scaling

If the radiation pressure at distance $d>R$ from the center of an isotropic black body star is found to be $$P_{rad}=\large{\frac{4\sigma T^4}{3c}}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{R^2}{d^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right],$$

a) How do I show that $P_{rad}$ obeys an inverse square law for $d \gg R$?

b) Why does the inverse square law scaling break down close to the stars surface?

Comment: A star doesn't have a solid surface. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere

Comment: What does this correspond to in the question? @PM2Ring

Comment: As that article says, the glowing surface of a star isn't actually a surface, it's like a translucent glowing fog. The Sun's photosphere is around 100 kilometers thick.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the question a), just use a Taylor expansion in the parameter $x= R/d \ll 1$, so that 
\begin{equation}
(1-x^2)^{3/2} \simeq 1- \frac{3}{2} x^2
\end{equation}
and then you obtain a inverse square law in $d$
\begin{equation}
P_{rad}= \frac{2\sigma T^4}{c} \frac{R^2}{d^2}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

As about (b):

> Why does the inverse square law scaling break down close to the stars surface?

$$ P_{\,d\approx R} = \lim_{d \to R} {\frac{4\sigma T^4}{3c}}\left[1-\left(1-\frac{R^2}{d^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right] = {\frac{4\sigma T^4}{3c}} $$

In other words, when you are at the star surface - you get as much radiation flux as possible, thus radiation density depends just on star surface temperature.

Comment: Thank you @AgniusVasiliauskas